# Why is my emt 1/2" conduit offset bend off?

Tags: electrical, conduit

I used the Klein shrinkage calculations on the handle.  For example for a 3 inch offset bend, you use 6 inch from point A plus 3/4" or 6 3/4" for point B.

So, why is it when I bend it, that it is 4" instead of 3"?

Also, even when I used a 2"inch offset with 22.5 angle -- Klein table calculation it is off again by 1". What am I doing wrong? I'm not going past the line?

Also, is their a tool snap collar to measure 180 degrees so I can be exact instead of eye sight when I reverse it the opposite way on mark B? I also noticed that if it isn't exactly 180 on point B it also causes the offset to not be flush with the ground.

Thank You

Comment: Are you referencing to the correct line on the bender?  It tends to have a lot of lines and arrows on it...  I don't know, always been a black art to me... I just wing it mostly.  Have been able to do some fairly complex stuff though.

Comment: I can tell you that it takes quite a bit of time and experience to properly bend conduit, and I know this comment is not what you may be looking for, but I always recommend the Ap "Conduit Bender Elite" it's the best I have seen and is well worth the $8.

Comment: I dis buy Ugly as you recommended as well, but maybe i will get the bender elite as you originally suggested.

Comment: Bending pipe is a art each brand of bender is slightly different and may have a different take up or shrinkage. The way I show apprentices is to have them bend with calculated values 2 different benders and see the differences. Getting the correct angle is the toughest part a couple degrees two much and your height will be wrong. I am lazy and almost always use 30 degrees for offsets and saddles since it is a simple 2:1 ratio and the handle will be perpendicular to the ground when bent. If you are running long you have over bent in most cases.

Comment: *"Fittings are cheap."*

Answer (score 2):

> So, why is it when I bend it, that it is 4" instead of 3"?

If your marks are accurate you are apparently overbending the angle. The shrink is not important with EMT since it can easily be cut to fit. Try making two marks 6" apart and see if you can accomplish a 3" offset with the bender standing up. See below.

> Also, even when I used a 2"inch offset with 22.5 angle -- Klein table calculation it is off again by 1". What am I doing wrong? I'm not going past the line?

You should bend offsets on ½" EMT in the standing position holding the conduit in one hand and the bender in the other. Bend the conduit down until the BOTTOM (not the top) of the conduit is even with the angle mark on the bender.

> Also, is their a tool snap collar to measure 180 degrees so I can be exact instead of eye sight when I reverse it the opposite way on mark B?

Yes, it is called a No-dog or an Anti-dog. But it will not work with a hand bender in the standing position. We just use our eye and sight down the conduit until it looks straight.

> I also noticed that if it isn't exactly 180 on point B it also causes the offset to not be flush with the ground.

This is called a dog-leg and can be remedied in ½" conduit fairly easily by inserting the conduit back into the bender and bending slightly perpendicular to the last bend. Larger conduit is done with a mechanical bender and that is when the No-dog comes in handy since with larger conduit it is very hard to fix a dog-leg.

I would recommend you get a copy of either the Benfield Conduit Bending Manual or Richard Cox's - Electricians Guide To Conduit Bending.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank u will look also to your suggeation on bending guides. When doing an offset you should just move it down and twist 180 degrees. The head of the shoe remains in the same position as A when standing.

Comment: "We just use our eye" - one trick for the second bend: Line up as best you can, and then just _barely_ start the second bend.  It's easier to tell if you're a few degrees off once the conduit flexes a bit, and you can still adjust if the conduit isn't bent, or not bent very much.

Comment: 6" between for a 3" offset is 30degree not 22.5 but other than that I agree.